# Mock Automapper map which has multiple sources

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, moq, xunit

I am writing a xunit test for a method that has a mapper with a couple of sources. But I was unable mock the automapper.

Mapper:

```
CreateMap<(Foo foo, Boo boo), Dto>()
 .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.foo.Name))
 .ForMember(d => d.Age, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.boo.Age));
```

Unit Test:

```
[Fact]
public void Handle_Test1()
{
    //Arrange
    var mocker = new AutoMocker(); 
    var sut = mocker.CreateInstance<Handler>();
    var mapperMock = mocker.GetMock<IMapper>();

    var foo = new Foo { Name = "Test" };
    var boo = new Boo { Age = 25 };
    var dto = new Dto { Name = "Test", Age = 25 };
    
    mapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map<Dto(new Tuple<Foo, Boo> (foo, boo ))).Returns(dto);

    //Also tried
    //mapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map<Dto(new { foo, boo })).Returns(dto);
}
```

I was able to get it working using the below line. but I am trying to solve the issue using the above approach. Can someone pinpoint what I am doing wrong here?

```
mapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map<Dto>(It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(dto)
```

Comment: There is no need to mock AM, just use the real thing. Also, check https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **not** mock AutoMapper.

I would create a loader and register the real [mappings](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) in AutoMocker.

```
public IMapper LoadMapper() {
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {                
        cfg.AddProfile<Profile1>();
        cfg.AddProfile<Profile2>();
    });
    return mapper.CreateMapper();
}
```

If you mock a mapper your test can be broken but the mapper can mask the problem.

And them [use](https://github.com/moq/Moq.AutoMocker#usage) it:

```
var mocker = new AutoMocker();
mocker.Use(LoadMapper());
```